# Error with this regex : var worksheet = (.*)\\};

Tags: java, regex, escaping, character

I got an error with this regex :

```
 Matcher worksheetMatcher = Pattern.compile(output).matcher("var worksheet = (.*)\\};");
```

Consider that output is a long html text that is read from web using jersey.

The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1150
```

I know that this error normally occurs when a character is not escaped but what is strange in this case is that the error still occurs if I try to match anything ".*", so that's why I'm here.

So if anyone have any idea why I get this error, please post here, your help is a lot appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the source prior to the `.matcher` call?

Comment: You've got the syntax backwards.  @barnesjd has the right answer.

Comment: You can have a look here at an example of how to create the Pattern and Matcher objects: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap the pattern string and `output`:

```
Matcher worksheetMatcher = Pattern.compile("var worksheet = (.*)\\};").matcher(output);
```